# How can I write a.b.c.someVariable in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In javascript there is this below given code.

```
A.B.C.D.someVariable= null;
```

I need to understand how to write this code in typescript ?

Comment: TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript, so you can use the exact same code.

Comment: I'm very new to this. I need to understand that these objects (A,B,C,D), do they need to be declared as classes or interfaces  ?

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript, even if A, B, C and D have been correctly declared.

Comment: You would write it as `A.B.C.D.someVariable= null;`

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
A.B.C.D.someVariable = null;
```

However in that case, someVariable won't be just yet another variable. It'll be considered as property for Object D which is a property of Object C which is a property of Object B which is a property of object A.

So you could do (in a very simplified term)

```
var A = { };
A.B = {};
A.B.C = {};
A.B.C.D = {};
A.B.C.D.someVariable = null;
```

Comment: So all these A,B,C,D should be declared as custom objects or these should be made as nested classes ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? I have used A, B, C, D as simple object. In your case, you could create customized object as needed.

Comment: I'm actually migrating from javascript to typescript, So some of my .js files have these object declaration in the files, So I was wondering how to achieve this using typescript.

Comment: class A{
  B:{
    C:{
      D:{
        someVariable:any
      }
    }
  }
}
var A= new A();